# TFCOREML install erorr

Tags: tensorflow, installation, coreml

When I try and install tfcoreml (package to conver tensorflow files to coreml) it gives me this error:

I have tried installing the coremltools seperatly in a python virtual enviroment...still doesn't work.

Rorys-MBP:~ roryhodgson$ cd tf-coreml 
Rorys-MBP:tf-coreml roryhodgson$ pip install -e .
Obtaining file:///Users/roryhodgson/tf-coreml
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.6.2 in /Users/roryhodgson/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tfcoreml==0.3.0) (1.15.4)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.1.0 in /Users/roryhodgson/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tfcoreml==0.3.0) (3.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in /Users/roryhodgson/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tfcoreml==0.3.0) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow>=1.5.0 in /Users/roryhodgson/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tfcoreml==0.3.0) (1.13.1)
Collecting coremltools>=0.8 (from tfcoreml==0.3.0)
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement coremltools>=0.8 (from tfcoreml==0.3.0) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for coremltools>=0.8 (from tfcoreml==0.3.0)

Answer (score 1):

At this point it appears you need to use Python 3.6 with coremltools. It's not working with Python 3.7 yet.

To solve this issue, it's easiest if you install Anaconda (the latest version, which is for Python 3.7) and then create a new virtual environment that uses Python 3.6. Now you can install coremltools / tfcoreml into this virtual environment.